# Calling an oracle procedure with optional parameter with nhibernate

Tags: oracle, nhibernate, plsql, procedure, option-type

I have a procedure like this:

```
Procedure MyProc(param1 IN VARCHAR2 default 'default_value', param2 IN VARCHAR2 default null);
```

To debug this in PL-SQL i'm doing:

```
MyPackage.MyProc(param2 => '20130301');
```

And it's mapped in Nhibernate inside a hbm file:

```
<sql-query name="MyMappedProc">
   <![CDATA[  call MyPackage.MyProc(param2 => :parametro2); ]]>
</sql-query>
```

and being called in application:

```
_Query = Session.GetNamedQuery("MyMappedProc");
_Query.SetParameter("parametro2", "value_var");

var lista = _Query.List<object>();
```

And I'm having this error:

`{"ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis"}`

Is there a way to call a procedure with optional parameters with NHibernate?

Thanks.

Comment: What SQL did NHibernate generate when you received this error message?

Comment: Is it not query.setstring ?

Comment: Need to see MyProc source code. is calling MyPackage.MyProc(param2 => '20130301'); on plsql works fine?

Comment: Rippo: no, calling setparameter for each parameter it wotks fine.

Comment: M.Heydari: On plsql it's ok, the proc run fine.

Comment: penfold: good idea, I'll try to intercept the generated sql, tks.

Comment: Use the configuration option show_sql=true. NHibernate will send all generated SQL to the console. See [here](http://nhforge.org/doc/nh/en/index.html#configuration-optional) for further information.

Answer (score 0):

How I'm doing this in production code right now

```
<sql-query name="Recalc">
    CALL P_DATA.RECALC.CONST_QUERY(:map, :id)
</sql-query>
```

and then from C# code

```
session.GetNamedQuery("Recalc").SetParameter("id", this.id)
    .SetParameter("map", "MyMap").ExecuteUpdate();
```

As usual ShowSQL or the [marvelous Ayende's NHibernate profiler](http://www.hibernatingrhinos.com/products/nhprof) are your friends